# How has Kodokan technique classification changed over the years?

Tags: judo, technique, history

Over the years several new techniques have been added to the Kodokan judo syllabus, and some variants of existing techniques have since gained their own official names.

How has technique classification evolved over the years?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original 41 throwing techniques (Gokyō no waza) were compiled in 1895:

| Group | Waza |
| --- | --- |
| Dai Ikkyō | *Hiza Guruma, Sasae Tsurikomi Ashi, Uki Goshi, Tai Otoshi, Ō Soto Gari, De Ashi Barai, Yoko Otoshi* |
| Dai Nikkyō | *Sumi Gaeshi, Ō Goshi, Ko Soto Gari, Koshi Guruma, Seoi Nage, Tomoe Nage, Tani Otoshi* |
| Dai Sankyō | *Okuri Ashi Barai, Harai Goshi, Ushiro Goshi, Ura Nage, Uchi Mata, Obi Otoshi, Hane Goshi* |
| Dai Yonkyō | *Uki Otoshi, Uki Waza, Daki Wakare, Kata Guruma, Hikkomi Gaeshi, Soto Makikomi, Tsuri Goshi, Utsuri Goshi, Ō Soto Otoshi, Tawara Gaeshi* |
| Dai Gokyō | *Yoko Guruma, Yoko Wakare, Uchi Makikomi, Ko Uchi Gari, Ashi Guruma, Seoi Otoshi, Yoko Gake, Harai Tsurikomi Ashi, Yama Arashi, Ō Soto Guruma* |

After this many new techniques were added to the recognized list of kodokan waza:

| Year | Te-waza⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ | Koshi-waza⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ | Ashi-waza⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ | Sutemi-waza⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ | Kansetsu-waza⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ | Shime-waza⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ | Osaekomi-waza⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1911 |  | Tsurikomi-goshi |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1920 | Sukui-nage | O-guruma | Ko-soto-gake O-uchi-gari | Hane-makikomi Sumi-otoshi | Ashi-garami⚠️ Ude-garami Ude-hishigi-juji-gatame Ude-hishigi-ude-gatame Ude-hishigi-waki-gatame Ude-hishigi-hara-gatame Ude-hishigi-hiza-gatame | Nami-juji-jime Gyaku-juji-jime Kata-juji-jime Hadaka-jime Okuri-eri-jime Kata-ha-jime ⚠️Do-jime | Hon-kesa-gatame Kuzure-kesa-gatame Kata-gatame Kami-shiho-gatame Kuzure-kami-shiho-gatame Yoko-shiho-gatame Tate-shiho-gatame |
| 1982 | Morote-gari Kuchiki-taoshi Kibisu-gaeshi Kouchi-gaeshi Uchi-mata-sukashi | ⚠️Daki-age | Osoto-gaeshi Ouchi-gaeshi Tsubame-gaeshi Uchi-mata-gaeshi Hane-goshi-gaeshi Harai-goshi-gaeshi | ⚠️Kani-basami ⚠️Kawazu-gake Harai-makikomi Osoto-makikomi Uchi-mata-makikomi |  |  |  |
| 1985 |  |  |  |  | Ude-hishigi-te-gatame Ude-hishigi-ashi-gatame Ude-hishigi-sankaku-gatame | Sode-guruma-jime Kata-te-jime Ryo-te-jime Tsukkomi-jime Sankaku-jime |  |
| 1997 | Ippon-seoi-nage | Sode-tsurikomi-goshi |  |  |  |  | *(✒️ Hon-kesa-gatame renamed Kesa-gatame)* |
| 2017 | Obi-tori-gaeshi | ❌<s>Daki-age</s> (*Technique removed)* |  | Kouchi-makikomi |  |  | Ushiro-kesa-gatame Uki-gatame Ura-gatame |

---

**Sources:**

<sup>• [柔道の技名称について](http://kodokanjudoinstitute.org/news/2017/04/epost-133/) (kodokanjudoinstitute.org)

• [講道館柔道　技名称一覧](https://web.archive.org/web/20130317215001/http://www.kodokan.org/j_waza/index.html#kansetsuwaza) ([English](https://web.archive.org/web/20130501155952/http://kodokan.org/e_waza/index.html))

• [*Creatividad y deporte: Consideraciones teóricas e investigaciones breves*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=4iTrCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA213&lpg=PA213&dq=%221997%22+katame+waza)

• [*The Principles of Osaekomi in Kodokan Judo*](http://www.kanosociety.org/Bulletins/pdf%20bulletins/Bulletinx38.pdf), The Kano Society Bulletin (2019)

• [*IJF referee Seminar Malaga 2014, Rules presentation*](http://99e89a50309ad79ff91d-082b8fd5551e97bc65e327988b444396.r14.cf3.rackcdn.com/up/2016/09/IJF_refereing_rules_explanator-1473863720.pdf)</sup>